# Doubts in Proposition 3.14 in Haim Brezis

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I was reading Haim Brezis Weak* topology section on page 6
4[image]

[image]

[image][image]

I understand everything except fact that

why in particular $|<f,x_i>|=0\implies \phi(f)=0$

Any Help in this regard will be appreciated Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\langle f,x_i\rangle=0$ for all $i$, then $tf\in V$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$. This implies 
$$
\phi(tf) = t \phi(f) <1 \quad \forall t\in \mathbb R,
$$
and $\phi(f)$ has to be zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir